# Django- Object representation based on a Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm testing a relatively simple model in my Django project:

```
class Restricted_Form(models.Model):
    Form = models.ForeignKey(Form)
    Authorized_Users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    Authorized_Groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

The point is to simply associate each form with some users, and groups. In the Django Admin, I want to have these Restricted_Fom objects listed, being represented by the "title" of the Form they are associated to (instead of having them all listed indistinguishably as *Restricted_Form object*) . I've tried something like

```
@property
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Form.title
```

but it's incorrect. How do I achieve this?

Is there a way to, for example, have another field, that's a string, that automatically populates itself based on the other field (the ForeignKey one, *Form*)?

Comment: delete @property

Comment: It works. If you'd like to, you can post it as an answer, so I can accept it and "close" this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@property is not required because **str**() is by default something like a property and if you print the object, output of **str**() is shown.